# First monday of the week value different on 2 computers

Tags: vba, date

I made a script allowing to automatically add the stats of the week, but i have an issu to display the date of the monday current week. On my laptop i got the 26th june which is correct, on the second one i got 3rd june... Of course i have to use is on the computer which provide the wrong answer, the second one...

How to solve this ? I tried to put the same language but same problem. Furthermore, when i use TODAY et WEEKDAY independantly, the values of the 2nd computer are the same that the first computer, its only occurs when i want to have the date of the first day of the current week.

Here is the code :

```
Range("A" & i + 5).Formula = "=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1"  '"week "[$-en-US]mmmm jj"th"
Range("A" & i + 5).NumberFormat = """week ""[$-en-US]mmmm dd""th"""
```

Results :

First laptop :

Result : 26 june

Expected : 26 june

Second laptop :

Result : 3 june

Expected : 26 june

Same code on both laptop

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Any differences in the regional settings (control panel) of the two computers?

Comment: Whats current date/time in 2nd laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format to `Range("A" & i + 5).NumberFormat = """week ""[$-409]mmmm dd""th"""`

Comment: Yes indeed the numberformat was involved in the issue. Do you know why it works one several computers but not on one of them ?

Comment: I think the number format (the part in [] confused excel). On my computer (locale setting so german) it was also displaying the 3 - no clue where this came from, so I assume it is related to the regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved it was only because of the NumerFormat..